# Ionic Framework failed to run on android emulator

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-emulator

I've followed this guide to install the android SDK: 
https://codesundar.com/ionic-cordova-environment-setup-for-windows-mac/

and setup environment files and all is correct

[image]

and got an error: **No valid Android SDK root found.**

This is my command line result:
[image]

---

I've also tried the `--no-native-run` and it still not working.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

On windows I add this variables: `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT C:\....\AppData\Local\Android\sdk` , `ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS C:\...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools`.
Try to add this, because your `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` is undefined;
After this reset your PC and try again.

Comment: Reset your PC??

Comment: Reboot the pc .